# What apparmor policy do I need in my click package for offline html5 application?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, webapps, apparmor, click-packages

Hello all you knowledgeable people.

I have created an ubuntu HTML5 application.

A simple, offline application.

You can browse it on github:
https://github.com/BigET/ResistorCalculator

In order for it to work, I had to use these policies:

```
{
    "template":"ubuntu-webapp",
    "policy_groups": [
        "webview",
        "networking"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.3
}
```

I understand why use "webview", I need execution access to webapp-container, but why do I need "networking" for? Without "networking the webapp-container complains that it cannot open the page and in dmesg output I see the apparmor denying the read access to my local html file.

Is there another policy that will not require me to demand from my users network access, but be able to browse my files from my application directory?

Thanks.